# Corrupted string through Sockets in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have the a problem transfering strings through sockets in Java. When i try to receive data from the server the data is transfered successfully but it's corrupted. I can't find out what is going wrong.

Here is the client piece of code:

```
public String getUserNameServerResult(String userNameParameter) {
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader socketReader;
    PrintWriter socketWriter;
    String userNameResultParameter = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER);
        socket.setSoTimeout(SERVER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
        socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        socketWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        socketWriter.println(numberRequest);
        socketWriter.flush();
        socketWriter.println(userNameParameter);
        socketWriter.flush();
        userNameResultParameter = socketReader.readLine();
        socketReader.close();
        socketWriter.close();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println(userNameResultParameter);
    } catch(IOException ioEx) {
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    }
        return userNameResultParameter;
}
```

The read line from readLine() method transfers a corrupted string.

Here is the server piece of code:

```
public synchronized void run(){
    System.out.println(new Date().toString()+" :\nAccepted client: "
            +socket.getInetAddress()+":"+socket.getPort()+"\n");
    try {
        while(!isInterrupted()) {
            String numberRequest = socketReader.readLine();
            if(numberRequest == null) {
                break;
            }
            switch(numberRequest) {
                case "1":    // Determines if the user name exists in the Database.
                    String userName = socketReader.readLine(); 
                    boolean isUserName = ServerRequest.isUserNameExists(userName);
                    socketWriter.println(isUserName);
                    socketWriter.flush();
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The "isUserName" variable is transfered and it gets corrupted in the client.

Can you help to solve this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: Corrupted how? Also, did you try and put a proxy to dump the data transferred between the client and server to find out which end is corrupting the data?

Comment: Also, do you **absolutely** need to use raw sockets? There's a lot of middleware at various levels of abstractions to help with writing servers. ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, QuickServer are all good alternatives if you don't want a web service / remoting mechanism.

Comment: isUserName is a boolean variable that determines if the user name exists in the database and before the socketWriter.println(isUserName) it has a correct form: true or false. But when it is transfered through the socket the result is become "[][][]  false" or "[][][]  true" where the "[][][]" is some unreadable data.

Comment: When are you initialising `socketWriter` on the server? Your example code doesn't include that. Are you absolutely certain nothing is written to it before the boolean? (You could probably verify this with a debugger by setting breakpoints inside `OutputStream.write()` for the outputstream implementation `Socket`s return.)

Answer (score 1):

`isUserName` is a `boolean`. Perhaps you meant `socketWriter.println(userName);` ?

Please use the code below to show us what the corrupted String looks like!

```
System.out.println(userNameResultParameter);
System.out.print("Chars:");
for (char c : userNameResultParameter.toCharArray())
    System.out.print(" 0x" + Integer.toHexString((int)c));
```

Comment: No, i want to transfer isUserName. As far as i know println() methods convert everything into string so it should transfer "true" or "false" as strings but they get corrupted when i receive them in the client. The result is something like "[][][]  false" where "[][][]" is some unreadable data. I can't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Two questions: is [][][] the same each time? Second, can you use the code I've edited into my post to dump the string that you're getting as a byte array we can look at?

Comment: Yes, the unreadble data is the same each time. When i put your code the result was: 

0xfffd 0xfffd 0x0 0x5 0x74 0x72 0x75 0x65

When i run the program for a second time, the result was the same.

Comment: Hmmm... and all of the other data is transmitted correctly? (`userName` and `numberRequest`)

Comment: Yes, actually i fixed the problem by moving the initialisation of the objects socketReader and socketWriter just before using them in the method and it works. Before that they were initialised in the constructor of the class. I don't know what is the difference but when i moved them in the method, it works.

Comment: That's not called "fixing a problem", if you don't exactly know what was the cause and what actions you took to fully resolve it.

Comment: Yes, i know but this is the only way the program runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I think, is with the construction of the `InputStreamReader`. By default, the reader is assuming that the encoding of the incoming character data is your platform's default encoding, however the `Writer` (on the server side) is sending UTF-8 data.

Try constructing the `InputStreamReader` like this:

`new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")`

Comment: I tried by modifying the InputStreamReader constructor but the result was the same.